# JSON - knockout.js - nested data

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have the following JSON received at my web application.

[image: JSON]

I have a knockout viewmodel:

```
var self = this;
self.ActiveAlarms = ko.observable();
```

and my JSON call:

```
$.getJSON("/api/Dashboard/ActiveAlarmsPerAlarmTypeForTurbine/591", function (data) {
    objVM.ActiveAlarms(data);
});
```

And I have my .cshtml page:

```
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <span data-bind="text: objVM.ActiveAlarms.turbine.name"></span>                                
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: listOfAlarmsPerAlarmType">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <span data-bind="text: alarmType.name"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

But nothing shows up... :-( - what am I missing here?

The rest of the webpage, viewmodel and the knouckout/json works very fine.

Comment: try `<span data-bind="text: objVM.ActiveAlarms().turbine.name"></span>`.

Comment: do you call ko.applyBindings() on any element with ActiveAlarms?

Comment: Bindings value: text: objVM.activeAlarms().turbine.name
Message: Cannot read property 'turbine' of undefined <span data-bind=​"text:​ objVM.activeAlarms()​.turbine.name">​</span>​ a.N {$parents: Array[0], $root: DashboardViewModel, ko: Object, $rawData: DashboardViewModel, $data: DashboardViewModel}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a number of things, are you binding the page correctly?

But one thing i noticed what this

```
  <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <span data-bind="text: objVM.ActiveAlarms().turbine.name"></span>                                
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: listOfAlarmsPerAlarmType">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <span data-bind="text: alarmType.name"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

You need to add parentheses to the observable object in the markup

Comment: I got it to work... :-)

            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot"></span><strong>Alarms</strong></span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-md-12" data-bind="with: objVM.activeAlarms">
                        <span data-bind="text: turbine.name"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>